# Most Popular Smart Contract (in DeFi)

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

We are a currently doing a research project on smart contracts. Amongst other things we are trying to find

- the most popular smart contracts in general and
- them most popular smart contracts in DeFi.

We understand popularity as a high adaption / usage of a certain smart contract by developers.

Every help and comment is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if you mean deployed contracts or undeployed/templates.

Here are my takes for both.

Deployed:

- Uniswap (all versions)
- Opensea contracts
- MetaMask swap
- Aave

Undeployed/templates:

- OpenZeppelin ERC20 & ERC721
- Gnosis Safe

Comment: Thanks! Do you have links wäre to find the code for those contracts?

Comment: I think all of them (unsure about metamask though) can be easily found from github, for example "openzeppelin github" serach will find that.

Answer (score 0):

Masterchef (originally by Sushiswap, based on Synthetix Rewards contract) is very popular and him and it's variants are used all over the place.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have links wäre to find the code for those contracts?

Comment: Welcome :) Masterchef you'll find in almost every dex or yield farm. For example here: https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-farm/blob/master/contracts/MasterChef.sol